# how to use TextArea as an inputStream

Tags: java

I want to use TextArea as an inputStream.Anyone have idea how this can be done...?

Comment: I have to question why this was tagged with applet. Do you mean an AWT TextArea or an HTML TextArea?

Comment: @Andrew Finnell "I have to question why this was tagged with applet".  I don't - the way it would be done in an applet is exactly the same as would be done in an application (barring any security restrictions for a sand-boxed applet - which is a different question).  Removed both applet related tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the string from it. Then use StringReader or ByteArrayInputStream after converting string to byte array.